# Expectation of Brownian motion $W^k, k = 2,4$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

G'day, I've just computed the expectation of $W^k$,

$W^k_{t} = \frac{k(k-1)}{2} \int_0^{t} E[W^{k-2}_{s}]ds $

However I am running into troubles when I calculate for the even moments. We know for the uneven moments the expectation is zero.

k = 2

$E[W^k_{t}]
= \frac{2(2-1)}{2} \int_0^{t}  E[W^{0}_{s}]ds = 1 \int_0^{t}  E[W^{k-2}_{s}]ds = t
$

k = 4

$E[W^k_{t}]
= \frac{4(4-1)}{2} \int_0^{t}  E[W^{4-2}_{s}]ds = 6 \int_0^{t}  E[W^{2}_{s}]ds = 3t^2
$

Can someone explain how we get *t* as solution for the case k = 2 and 3$t^{2}$ for the case of k = 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean $\mathbb{E}[W^k_t]$ on the left-hand side of your formulas. 
Anyway, for $k=2$ you use the fact that $W^0_t = 1$, while for $k=4$ you have to use $\mathbb{E}[W^2_s] = s$.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer! However, can you explain to me like a small child how you get from  $6 \int_0^{t}  E[W^{2}_{s}]ds$  to  $3t^2$? I know $E[W^{0}_{s}] = 1$ and $E[W^{2}_{s}] = s$, however how do you get to 3t^2 , where does the power to the 2 and the integer 3 come from?

Comment: Sure. Since $\mathbb{E}[W^2_s] = s$ and the integral of $s$ is $s^2/2$, you have $6\int_0^t \mathbb{E}[W_s^2] ds = 6\int_0^t s \, ds = 6 \frac{t^2}{2} = 3 t^2$.

Comment: Thanks you legend you! You are saving my grade :). I have another question regarding martingales, is it ok if I link you to the new question?